# TensorFlow, training produces 3 ckpt files, which one is correct? (Music_RNN_RBM)

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm giving a shot at [Music_RNN_RBM](https://github.com/hy0kl/Music_RNN_RBM)

I've trained the model and, as instruction said a ckpt file is generated, problem is that in the directory for each epoch saved I've three .ckpt .data .index and .meta
example:

```
model.ckpt-151800.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-151800.index
model.ckpt-151800.meta
```

Now, next step would be to generate trough

```
python rnn_rbm_generate.py <path_to_ckpt_file>
```

I've tried to do like this for each type of file

```
python3 rnn_rbm_generate.py model.ckpt-151800.index
```

But I get this error each time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnn_rbm_generate.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1])
  File "rnn_rbm_generate.py", line 43, in main
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model_checkpoint_path'
```

I don't get what I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, each checkpoint consists of a `.data`, `.meta`, and a `index` file.

However, TensorFlow also creates a `checkpoints` file, which keeps track of all the checkpoints in the output directory. It contains a link `model_checkpoint_path` to the most recent checkpoint which is what your model is looking for.

So to answer your question, the path you are providing should contain this `checkpoints` file.

Comment: Hey, there is a checkpoint file in my folder, but is not a `.ckpt`
I tried to run this one as:

`python3 rnn_rbm_generate.py parameter_checkpoints/checkpoint`

it returned me this series of errors:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file parameter_checkpoints/checkpoint: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to u
se a different restore operator?

         [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]`

Comment: Did it!
just run:
`rnn_rbm_generate.py parameter_checkpoints`
it automatically found the right checkpoint I assume

Answer (score 0):

There's a [function to load the latest one](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/latest_checkpoint). Use it to load it, and create a proper saved model, checkpoints are used as back-up, or to continue training afterwards, not to serve. The 'checkpoints' file prouast mentioned is loaded in by the function I mentioned, it's information about the files that are being created, and can't be loaded. Questions, ask away

EDIT:
besides the code code in your repo indicates that you can also provide the full folder, instead of a file.